# Should I consider the Simple XML Framework for Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, simple-framework

Lately the **[Simple XML Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)** gained popularity and some [sites](http://simple.sourceforge.net/articles.php) are presenting it.

I am thinking about replacing **Apache Xerces-J** with a new framework and I am considering **Simple** to be its successor.

Do you have any experiences with **Simple**?
What are its advantages and disadvantages?
Is it recommended for the use with enterprise software/within a servlet container or application server?

Comment: By saying you want to replace Apache Xerces-J do you mean replacing your usage of DOM/SAX with Simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JAXB is the [enterprise standard](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/jaxb-xml-binding-standard.html) for converting objects to/from XML.  There are many implementations:   [Metro](http://jaxb.java.net/) (the reference implementation included in Java SE 6), [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) (I'm the tech lead), [Apache JaxMe](http://ws.apache.org/#Archived_Projects) (no longer maintained), etc.

In terms of enterprise, JAXB is part of Java EE 5 and [Java EE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html).  It is the binding layer for both Java Web Service standards:  JAX-WS (SOAP) and JAX-RS (REST).  This means it is supported by all the application server vendors:  Oracle, IBM, SAP, JBoss, etc.

All JAXB implementations are also well supported in Spring:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Spring

For a comparison of JAXB and Simple check out:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html

Comment: I have looked at your reference, and I don't see the point that makes '''Simple''' simple, though I have to admit I never looked at their page. But after having read that reference, I advocate for JAXB, too.

Comment: Its a matter of opinion, however JAXB has gone about very simple POJO to XML scenarios in a rather obtuse manner. It is also a very heavy weight solution. Simple works on Java 1.5 and up, as well as Android, and Google App Engine, JAXB does not.

Comment: @Ng - If you check out my comparison (http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html) you will see there is little difference between the JAXB and Simple approaches.  JAXB implementations (Metro, MOXy, JaxMe, etc) work perfectly fine on Java 1.5+.  If I'm not mistaken you are a contributor on Simple?

Comment: but JAXB does not work on Android, so at certain point, u got to switch to simple for Android.