# Save data in an XML file

Tags: java, xml

I have an application where in i need to save the data input by a user in a form in an XML file at a specified location and i need to perform this using Java . I am relatively very new to XML handling in java. I would like some suggestions as to how to start the task .

Any code snippets and links will be helpful ...

Thank You

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is very good framework [JAXB](http://jaxb.dev.net) for this also there is [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)

But I have used this  [`XStream`](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)

```
Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes");
joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));
joe.setFax(new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));
```

Now, to convert it to XML, all you have to do is make a simple call to XStream:

```
String xml = xstream.toXML(joe);
```

The resulting XML looks like this:

```
<person>
  <firstname>Joe</firstname>
  <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
  <phone>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>1234-456</number>
  </phone>
  <fax>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>9999-999</number>
  </fax>
</person>
```

**Also See**

- [JA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803861/what-is-fastest-xml-serialization-framework)[XB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735842/should-i-consider-the-simple-xml-framework-for-java)
- [where-i-can-find-a-detailed-comparison-of-java-xml-frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855324/where-i-can-find-a-detailed-comparison-of-java-xml-frameworks)

Comment: Seconded. This is the simplest ay I've found

Comment: +1 - Remember that JAXB is a specification (JSR-222) with multiple implementations:  Metro (the reference implementation, included in Java SE 6), EclipseLink MOXy (I'm the tech lead), Apache JaxMe, etc.  Check out this XStream comparsion (http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html), and this Simple comparison (http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-simple.html).

Comment: Please help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230086/generate-xml-from-a-text-file-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/) library.  It's very simple to convert POJOs (plain old java objects) to and from XML.  I have a [blog post](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/xstream-introduction-and-java-collections-serialization-problem-workaround/) detailing some of the gotchas.

Comment: Check out the following for more gotchas:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906855/parse-google-geocode-with-xstream

Answer (score 1):

There are many open source libraries, but I would simply use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/), the standard. Although I have to say the XStream library suggested by other answerers looks very promising, too!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using xstream (http://x-stream.github.io/). XStream's API is very simple:

```
YourObjectGraph yourData=buildYourData();
XStream xstream=new XStream();
String yourXML=xstream.toXml(yourData);
// do something with your shiny XML
```

Importing is just as easy:

```
YourObjectGraph yourData=(YourObjectGraph)xstream.fromXml(yourXml);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to save and load properties as XML file

to save xml :

```
storeToXML(OutputStream os, String comment);
storeToXML(OutputStream os, String comment, String encoding);
```

to load xml :

```
loadFromXML(InputStream in)
```

here is an example :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File(getPath());
        if (!file.exists()) {
            Properties p1 = new Properties();
            p1.setProperty("A", "Amir Ali");
            try {
                writeXML(p1);
                System.out.println("xml saved to " + getPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
            try {
                Properties p2 = readXML();
                System.out.println(p2.getProperty("A"));
            } catch (InvalidPropertiesFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void writeXML(Properties properties) throws IOException {
        if (properties != null) {
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(getPath());
            properties.storeToXML(os, null);
        }
    }

    public static Properties readXML() throws InvalidPropertiesFormatException, IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(getPath());
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.loadFromXML(is);
        return p;
    }
    
    private static String getPath() {
        return System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "properties.xml";
    }
}
```