# Generate XML from a text file in Java

Tags: java, xml, io, xstream

This is my text file:

```
5625145214 6
8562320154 2
8542154157 5
6325145214 5
5214214584 6
5625142224 3
8562456754 1
```

I want to use `XStream` to generate `XML` file:

This is my code:

```
    private static void generateXml() throws IOException {
    XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());

    String line = null;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Unique Numbers.txt"))) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String xml = xStream.toXML(line);
            System.out.println(xml);
        }
    }

}
```

How can i generate `xml` file? I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't how you want your xml, but the following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        generateXml();
    }
     private static void generateXml()  {
            XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());

            String line = null;
            try{
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Unique Numbers.txt"))) ;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String xml = xStream.toXML(line);
                    System.out.println(xml);
                }
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }

            }
```

would print :

```
<string>5625145214 6</string>
<string>8562320154 2</string>
<string>8542154157 5</string>
<string>6325145214 5</string>
<string>5214214584 6</string>
<string>5625142224 3</string>
<string>8562456754 1</string>
```

Comment: Should i write this xml to a file?

Comment: Yes, if you'd like to. Depends on what you want to achieve.